# Comparing a dictionary and a list to search for equivalent value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict={    20009    'Music',
    20010   'Disasters',
    20011   'Bill Clinton',
    20012   'Religion',
    20013   'Olympics'}
```

The dictionary was created by:

```
def get_pair(line):
  key, sep, value = line.strip().partition("\t")
  return int(key), value

with open("TopicMapped.txt") as fd:    
           d = dict(get_pair(line) for line in fd)

print(d)
```

On the other hand I have a list `n= 20009, 20010, 20011, 20012, 20013`
I want to see if each value in `n` exists in `dict` and if it does, the corresponding string should be printed (eg. Music) in the same order as the values in n. Like Music, Disasters, Bill Clinton, Religion, Olympics.

I am getting a little confused because of the dictionary elements. 
This is what I have tried

```
y_d=clf.predict_log_proba(mat_tmp_test)
order=np.argsort(y_d, axis=1) 
n=clf.classes_[order[:, -5:]] #this is a numpy array of top 5 probabilities

f.write("Top 5 probable topics: \t")
    for row in k:
        s=', '.join(str(x) for x in row)  # to put them in a string form
        f.write(s)
        print(s) # I get 20009, 20010, 20011, 20012, 20013
        f.write("\n")
   for item in s:           #adding the comparison code here
       if item in d.keys():
           print d[item]
```

Output: I don't receive any output except for that of `print(s)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for item in n:
    if item in dict.keys():
        print dict[item]
```

Note: it is bad practice to name a dictionary "dict" since `dict()` is the name of a built-in function in python.

Comment: I have edited my question including the code you provided. However, something doesn't seem to working out as I don't receive any output. I have added in further details of my code too.

Comment: You're doing `for item in s:` where `s` looks like a list of strings whereas the keys are integers, not strings. The `if` will always fail. You have two choices: 1) make `s` a list of integers; 2) convert the dictionary keys from integers to strings

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `get` from the dictionary. It defaults to `None` if the key does not exist:

```
for i in n:
    print(d.get(i))
```

Output:

```
Music
Disasters
Bill Clinton
Religion
Olympics
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to include more details of my dictionary and list. On adding this to my code, I only receive None, none, none, none. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @minks . Why are you putting this `s=', '.join(str(x) for x in row) ` in to string form? You referred to it as a list originally. Why not just create a list to store that data?

Comment: I was actually trying to get rid of a numpy array. I thought it would be easier to get it into string form and more presentable without the brackets because I am printing this out to a webpage. But if it makes more sense, how can I convert this numpy array to a list though?

Comment: Well, if you have a string like this: "1,2,3,4". You can simply do split(','), which will split the string on comma and create a list of those items. Throw this in to your interpreter to see what happens: `"1,2,3,4,5".split(',')`

Comment: But then how is that a list again, it gives me ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']. Isn't this again strings within a list? Because the comparator doesn't seem to recognize s and gives none again

Comment: OK. So, when you are iterating in that list, and you know that you need an int just cast to an int like this: `d.get(int(i))`. i being each item in your list: e.g. `for i in n`. Or, off the top of my head can just do this and get a list of ints directly: `map(int, "1, 2, 4".split(','))`